# Best method to investigate treatment effect after creating a Matched control group using Gentic Matching (with replacement)?

Tags: matching, treatment-effect, genetic-algorithms, observational-study

Project background:

I have data on patients who received varying amounts of therapy dose during treatment of stroke-induced paralysis. I wish to investigate if there are differences in motor-function recovery between the group of patients who received a Low Dose (<15 hours) of occupational therapy, and the group that received a High Dose (>30 hours) of occupational therapy. I have measures indicating their motor-function abilities (WMFT scores to be exact) before and after they received therapy.

Because the Therapy Dose (High/Low) was not randomly assigned to patients, we had to account for confounders before exploring differences between the High Dose (HD) and Low Dose (LD) groups. The confounders that we considered included Demographic information, medical information (stroke severity/damage), and the functional abilities of patients (WMFT scores, etc) before they started receiving therapy.

We accounted for confounders by using Matching. Via Genetic Matching, we picked subjects from the HD group that were most similar to the LD group subjects and constructed a Matched HD group. However, because some HD patients were the best matches for multiple LD patients and the matches were selected with replacement, these HD patients were included multiple times in the Matched HD group.

Current challenge:

After matching, I now wish to statistically test if the LD and HD group-subjects are different in terms of their motor function after receiving treatment. There are several approaches that I have been considering and there are possibly better ones that I am not aware of. I need help understanding what is the best approach and why.

The approaches that I have considered include:

1)  Simple Linear regression:

- Independent variable – Therapy Dose (indicated by 1 or 0)
- Dependent variable - Motor function test score after treatment (Genetic Matching ensures that the LD and HD groups are balanced for Motor Function scores before treatment)

2)  Multiple Linear Regression:

- Independent variable: Therapy dose (1/0) + every other Matching variable that was balanced using Genetic Matching
- Dependent- Motor function test score after treatment

3)  Using paired tests (paired t-test/ Wilcoxon signed rank test) to investigate whether the groups are significantly different in terms of their motor function 
after therapy

Note that In this case, it isn't appropriate to use unpaired t-tests/ non-parametric tests like the Mann-whitney U after matching to determine if the groups are significantly different, because these tests assume that there is "independence within samples". This assumption is violated as the matched HD set is constructed with replacement, and several samples are repeated multiple times. I also cannot remove the repeated measures as they are required to ensure that the 2 samples are balanced in terms of the matching covariates.

Additional info for R:
The Matching package allows me to specify what variable of interest I want to use for observing the treatment effect. When I do, and get the summary of the model I get results like this

> Estimate...  -0.65908  AI SE......  1.8227  T-stat.....  -0.36159 
>   p.val......  0.71766
>
> Original number of observations..............   210
>   Original number of treated obs...............   87
>   Matched number of observations...............   87
>   Matched number of observations  (unweighted).  87

However I have noticed that R uses t and p values to indicate significance of coefficients even when I perform linear regression, so this doesn't answer my original question.

Comment: If you're using `Matching` in R to perform the genetic matching, you should use their built-in function for estimating the treatment effect and it's SE, making sure to use the built-in feature for bias-correction due to inexact matching on continuous variables. `teffects` in Stata does the same thing and has some great documentation. If you're comfortable doing something fancy like genetic matching, you might consider using TMLE, which is highly robust to model misspecification and also relies on machine learning. The `tmle` package in R makes this straightforward.

Comment: If you're using `MatchIt` in R you might just switch to using `Matching`, which was written by the developers of genetic matching and is very user-friendly. Check out my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401640/estimation-of-average-treatment-effect-based-on-nearest-neighbor-matching/401724#401724) for an example

Comment: @ Thank you Noah! :) So I just tried using the Match function while mentioning the variable of interest to observe the treated effect and edited my question to include the results. However, I still cannot completely understand what test is being used and I that's something I still need to know